# Autofac using DynamicProxy2 Interception with WcfIntegration

Tags: autofac, interception, iinterceptor

I'm struggling to wire up a service interface using WcfIntegration with an IInterceptor.

There are examples for each in the autofac documentation but nothing that combines the two.

Here is the documentation for the [WcfIntegration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration) and look here for the [DynamicProxy2](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DynamicProxy2)
documentation.

Has anyone successfully wired up an interceptor with WcfIntegration using Autofac?

Example code I'd have expected to work:

```
            builder.Register(c => new CacheInterceptor())
            .Named<IInterceptor>("cache-calls");

        builder
            .RegisterType<ChannelFactory<IEnquiryService>>()
            .AsSelf()
            .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("endpointConfigurationName", "EnquiryService"))
            .SingleInstance();

        builder
            .Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<IEnquiryService>>().CreateChannel())
            .As<IEnquiryService>()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy("cache-calls");
```

EDIT:

Seems like a bug has been logged on [autofac site.](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=361&q=dynamicproxy2) Any work arounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this has been raised as a bug on autofac bugtracker, If no one can see a workaround, I'll mark this as the answer. They have uploaded a console app reproducing the exact scenario.

http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=361&q=dynamicproxy2

**EDIT: This has now been fixed in the latest version**